# Chrome extension for selenium video recording

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, selenium-chromedriver, recording

Microsoft Expression Encoder no longer supports video recording from selenium .net.

I have an idea if it's possible to create a chrome extension with a trigger that starts video recording when the browser or tab opens and saves the recorded video after the close.

in selenium it's possible to start chromedriver with enabled extension. but impossible to click on the extension without third-party app. that restricts recording in headless mode.

I have never been worked on extension development. anyone can advise? has my idea chances to become real?

Answer (score 0):

Are using any cloud testing platforms? Like https://saucelabs.com/ or https://crossbrowsertesting.com/. I'm used those services to record my scripts running.

Comment: no i want to implement it into selenium for my companys local server